# How to add the menu in the group using the id?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I'm working on my android app to add the menu in the group using with the id. I have got a problem with adding the menu in the group because it will adding the menu on the bottom of the navigation drawer without adding the group using with the id.

Here is what it have show:

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
menu.addSubMenu(R.id.nav_group1, 1, 100, "test1")
      .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
menu.addSubMenu(R.id.nav_group1, 2, 101, "test2")
      .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
menu.addSubMenu(R.id.nav_group1, 3, 102, "test4")
      .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
menu.addSubMenu(R.id.nav_group1, 4, 103, "test new folder")
      .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
menu.addSubMenu(R.id.nav_group1, 5, 104, "test new folder backup")
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
```

And I have also tried this:

```
menu.add(R.id.nav_group1, 1, 100, "test1")
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
menu.add(R.id.nav_group1, 2, 101, "test2")
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
menu.add(R.id.nav_group1, 3, 102, "test4")
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
menu.add(R.id.nav_group1, 5, 104, "test new folder")
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
menu.add(R.id.nav_group1, 5, 104, "test new folder backup")
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
```

And I have also tried this:

```
menu.addSubMenu(R.id.second_group, 1, 100, "test1")
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
menu.addSubMenu(R.id.second_group, 2, 101, "test2")
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
menu.addSubMenu(R.id.second_group, 3, 102, "test4")
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
menu.addSubMenu(R.id.second_group, 5, 104, "test new folder backup")
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
```

Full code:

```
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
menu.add(R.id.nav_group1, 1, 100, "test1")
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
menu.add(R.id.nav_group1, 2, 101, "test2")
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
menu.add(R.id.nav_group1, 3, 102, "test4")
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
menu.add(R.id.nav_group1, 5, 104, "test new folder")
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
menu.add(R.id.nav_group1, 5, 104, "test new folder backup")
     .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
```

activity_main_drawer.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_inbox"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_inbox_24"
            android:title="Inbox1" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_important"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_important_24"
            android:title="Important" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_outbox"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_outbox_24"
            android:title="Outbox" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_sent"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_sent_mail_24"
            android:title="Sent" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_drafts"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_draft_24"
            android:title="Drafts" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_spam"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_spam_24"
            android:title="Spam" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_trash"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_trash_24"
            android:title="Trash" />
    </group>

    <group android:visible="false" android:id="@+id/second_group" />

    <group android:id="@+id/nav_group1">
        <item
            android:title="Folders" />
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/nav_group2">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_create_new_folder"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
            android:title="Create New" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is I want to add the menu items in the group using with the id called `nav_group1`.

Like this:

[image]

Can you please show me an example how I could add the menu into the group using with the id?

Comment: I'm having some difficulties understanding what your question is.

Comment: @Shawn What you dont understand?

Comment: What I'm trying to do  is I want to add the menu items in the group using with the id called `nav_group1`. Is that not hard to understand what I want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I'm struggling with the way the question is worded, remember I'm volunteering my time to help. Is this an existing menuGroup or a new menuGroup? Is the problem that you are experiencing that the menuItems are being added individually and not as a group?

Comment: @Shawn yes I do have a problem with the menuitems that are not being adding in a group when I am using the group id `nav_group1`. Please see the screenshots in my question what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what your navDrawer is currently displaying.

Comment: @Shawn yes, it is currently displaying the menuitems on the bottom. Please see the first screenshot in my question that is what my navDrawer is currently displaying.

Comment: I think I get what your after know, correct me if I'm wrong. You aren't having a problem adding the menuGroup, your problem is with where the menuGroup is positioned in the navDrawer?

Comment: Yes that is correct.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `orderInCategory`. You've already assigned the order to menuItems you've added programmatically.

The problem is in your XML, when `orderIncategory` numbers arent assigned a number they are given a value of zero as the default. When you programmatically added the menuItems you assigned a higher `orderInCategory` positioning those menu items at the bottom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
           android:orderInCategory="10">
        ...
    </group>

    <group android:visible="false" android:id="@+id/second_group" />

    <group android:id="@+id/nav_group1"
           android:orderInCategory="100">
        <item
            android:title="Folders" />
    </group>

    <group android:id="@+id/nav_group2"
           android:orderInCategory="200">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_create_new_folder"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
            android:title="Create New" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

I don't have access to android stuido right know but In your java, you could also try setting `inOrderNumber` to zero.

```
menu.addSubMenu(R.id.nav_group1, 1, 0, "test1")
      .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_folder_24);
```

Comment: I would expect better than this as I need the java code to add the menu items in the group. I have tried it and it dont work.

Comment: No I didn't do anything. Why is that?

Comment: Nice answer Shawn  we keep leaning from one another  :)